# Ignore filter function if value not present tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr

If I had a tibble such that

```
tib <- tibble(col1 = c("a","a","b","b"))
```

and I filtered

```
filter(tib, col1 == "c"),
```

instead of returning nothing in the output, how could I get a result that the entire tibble would be returned?

Comment: `dplyr::filter(tib, !"c" %in% col1 | col1 == "c")`

Comment: Thanks r2evans for the solution I have been looking for since the beginning of the day!